# Can the pronoun 'its' referring to a clause as a whole be placed at the beginning of the next sentence?

Tags: pronouns

> (1)Bill doesn't want to go and **that**'s the problem.

> (2)Bill doesn't want to go and **it**'s the problem.

I understand (1) is good, but (2) is not natural,
because **it** referring to the entire clause cannot be at the beginning of the next sentence.
But the use of **its** in (3) seems natural though **it** refers to the preceding clause as a whole. Why?

> (3)The French throw away 20 to 30 kg of food per person per year and **its** cost is estimated to be 20 billion euro a year.

Comment: In example 3 "its" does not refer to the clause, but to the food. The clause does not have a cost, the food does.

Comment: Notice that in 2 you're using the contraction of "it is", but in 3 you're using the possessive "the cost of it". These are unrelated uses and the rules are different.

Comment: Certainly. << Bill does not want to go. It's a problem. >> // (1) is fine. (2) probably requires something more forceful (this or that). //// (3) uses _it_ with non-clausal referent, as stated above. However, the referent is not clear; I'd use '... per year and/; the total cost is estimated ...'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can, yes, provided that the next sentence is preceded with a full stop, and not a conjunction.

Example 1:
*I can't get to him in time and it's frustrating!* (sounds like poor phrasing)

Example 2:
*I can't get to him in time. It's frustrating!* (more proper)

However, if you're referring to "its" rather than "it's", then it will not be exactly a sound use of "its":

Example 3:
*What he said was "I will fight fire with fire", and its implications are unsavory to them.*

Example 4:
*What he said was "I will fight fire with fire". Its implications are unsavory to them.*